# NPM uninstall -g yo, yo still works

Tags: node.js, npm, yo

I'm a noob at my wits end and have already consulted a couple of friends who know (much) more than me. Sorry if these are dumb questions. Hoping you guys can help.

I think it has to do with some weird NPM pathing issues, but I can't figure them out. `npm install -g generator-xxx` follows through with success, but when I run Yo, no generators are listed.

Tried `npm update -g npm` - no dice. Npm remains out of date. This is also true of `n` and most (but not all? I think?) npm modules.

I tried to start from scratch, followed [NPM's advice](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall) for a complete fresh start. Reinstalled node from node.js's website. Happily, node is up to date, but npm is *still* several released behind (`2.11.3`).

The most disturbing part of all of this: `npm uninstall -g npm` and the packages still work, which makes me think I've got a rogue npm installation rumbling around somewhere in my box, but I cannot find it.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Comment: What paths do you get from `npm root -g` and either `which -a npm` (terminal) or `gcm npm` (PowerShell)?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `/Users/zachherring/.node/lib/node_modules` and `/usr/local/bin/npm` respectively.

Comment: You appear to have multiple installations of npm, with one executing (in `/usr/local`) and updating the other (in `~/.node`) rather than itself. Or, at least, `npm` [is configured](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#npmrc-files) to work on the latter path.

Comment: Ah. Do you have any resources you might be able to point me to to rectify this? How can I find both installations and/or fix the pathing? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node loads modules from several locations by default, and is also influenced by your environment. Take a look in these locations to see if you have modules installed that you weren't aware of.

- `$HOME/.node_modules`
- `$HOME/.node_libraries`
- `<prefix>/lib/node_modules` (where `<prefix>` is e.g. `/usr` or `/usr/local`
- Any path(s) in the `$NODE_PATH` environment variable
- `./node_modules` if it exists in the current directory
- `../node_modules` if it exists
- ... and so on up the tree, all the way to the root of the filesystem

Comment: `npm list -g` - is this a list from _all_ of those locations or just `USERNAME/.node/lib/` ?

I've checked where you've listed - none of those locations existed except the `.node/lib` location.

Thanks!

Comment: `npm list -g` should list global modules only, which I am guessing in your case are under `$HOME/.node/lib`. `npm list` without the `-g` flag will look at local modules, e.g. those found in say `./node_modules` relative to your current path.